# iTextPDF 7 - HTML with base64 inline images to PDF. PNG ok, but JPG FAIL

Tags: html, itext, itext7

I have 5 base64 inline images in my html. 4 PNG and 1 JPG. 
The process fail when converting html to PDF. When deleting the JPG image node from html, it works ok!

Java code for `iTextPDF7`:

```
HtmlConverter.convertToPdf(new File(src), new File(dest));
```

JPG base64 HTML img:

```
<img content-height="4.22cm" content-width="7.45cm" src="data:image/jpg;base64,/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQEBLAEsAAD/4Q4kRXhpZgAATU..........
```

PNG base64 HTML img:

```
<img content-width="scale-down-to-fit" width="100%" src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAG4AAACrCAY........
```

I am getting this error message:

> Bad Base64 input character at 76: 37(decimal) 18:34:13.582 [main]
>   ERROR c.i.h.r.resource.ResourceResolver - Unable to retrieve image
>   with given base URI (file:/D:/PDFCONVERTER/ITEXPDF7/html/) and image
>   source path
>   (data:image/jpg;base64,/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQEBLAEsAAD/4Q4kRXhpZgAATU0AKgAAAAgAB.................)

```
java.net.MalformedURLException: unknown protocol: data
    at java.net.URL.<init>(URL.java:600) ~[na:1.8.0_72]
    at java.net.URL.<init>(URL.java:490) ~[na:1.8.0_72]
    at com.itextpdf.html2pdf.resolver.resource.UriResolver.resolveAgainstBaseUri(UriResolver.java:117) ~[html2pdf-1.0.1.jar:na]
    at com.itextpdf.html2pdf.resolver.resource.ResourceResolver.retrieveImage(ResourceResolver.java:122) ~[html2pdf-1.0.1.jar:na]
    at com.itextpdf.html2pdf.attach.impl.tags.ImgTagWorker.<init>(ImgTagWorker.java:72) [html2pdf-1.0.1.jar:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method) [na:1.8.0_72]
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62) [na:1.8.0_72]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45) [na:1.8.0_72]
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423) [na:1.8.0_72]
    at com.itextpdf.html2pdf.attach.impl.DefaultTagWorkerFactory.getTagWorker(DefaultTagWorkerFactory.java:88) [html2pdf-1.0.1.jar:na]
    at com.itextpdf.html2pdf.attach.impl.DefaultHtmlProcessor.visit(DefaultHtmlProcessor.java:224) [html2pdf-1.0.1.jar:na]
    at com.itextpdf.html2pdf.attach.impl.DefaultHtmlProcessor.visit(DefaultHtmlProcessor.java:240) [html2pdf-1.0.1.jar:na]
    at com.itextpdf.html2pdf.attach.impl.DefaultHtmlProcessor.visit(DefaultHtmlProcessor.java:240) [html2pdf-1.0.1.jar:na]
    at com.itextpdf.html2pdf.attach.impl.DefaultHtmlProcessor.visit(DefaultHtmlProcessor.java:240) [html2pdf-1.0.1.jar:na]
    at com.itextpdf.html2pdf.attach.impl.DefaultHtmlProcessor.visit(DefaultHtmlProcessor.java:240) [html2pdf-1.0.1.jar:na]
    at com.itextpdf.html2pdf.attach.impl.DefaultHtmlProcessor.processDocument(DefaultHtmlProcessor.java:200) [html2pdf-1.0.1.jar:na]
    at com.itextpdf.html2pdf.attach.Attacher.attach(Attacher.java:78) [html2pdf-1.0.1.jar:na]
    at com.itextpdf.html2pdf.HtmlConverter.convertToDocument(HtmlConverter.java:298) [html2pdf-1.0.1.jar:na]
    at com.itextpdf.html2pdf.HtmlConverter.convertToPdf(HtmlConverter.java:244) [html2pdf-1.0.1.jar:na]
    at com.itextpdf.html2pdf.HtmlConverter.convertToPdf(HtmlConverter.java:231) [html2pdf-1.0.1.jar:na]
    at com.itextpdf.html2pdf.HtmlConverter.convertToPdf(HtmlConverter.java:193) [html2pdf-1.0.1.jar:na]
    at com.itextpdf.html2pdf.HtmlConverter.convertToPdf(HtmlConverter.java:167) [html2pdf-1.0.1.jar:na]
    at com.itextpdf.html2pdf.HtmlConverter.convertToPdf(HtmlConverter.java:147) [html2pdf-1.0.1.jar:na]
    at cl.cgr.sistradoc.pdfconverter.itextpdf7.Html2Pdf.createPdf(Html2Pdf.java:78) [classes/:na]
    at cl.cgr.sistradoc.pdfconverter.itextpdf7.Html2Pdf.main(Html2Pdf.java:54) [classes/:na]
18:34:13.587 [main] ERROR c.i.h.a.impl.DefaultHtmlProcessor - Worker of type com.itextpdf.html2pdf.attach.impl.tags.DivTagWorker unable to process com.itextpdf.html2pdf.attach.impl.tags.ImgTagWorker
```

iTxtPDF 7 does not support JPG base64 html inline images?
Thanks for your help!!!

Diego

Update 2019-02-19
My POM:

```
    <properties>
        <itext.version>7.1.5</itext.version>
    </properties>
  <dependencies>
  <!-- iText 7 License Key Library -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.itextpdf</groupId>
        <artifactId>itext-licensekey</artifactId>
        <!-- version>2.0.4</version--><!-- for itext 7.0.4 -->
        <version>3.0.4</version><!-- for itext 7.1.5 -->
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.itextpdf</groupId>
        <artifactId>kernel</artifactId>
        <version>${itext.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.itextpdf</groupId>
        <artifactId>io</artifactId>
        <version>${itext.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.itextpdf</groupId>
        <artifactId>layout</artifactId>
        <version>${itext.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.itextpdf</groupId>
        <artifactId>forms</artifactId>
        <version>${itext.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.itextpdf</groupId>
        <artifactId>pdfa</artifactId>
        <version>${itext.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.itextpdf</groupId>
        <artifactId>pdftest</artifactId>
        <version>${itext.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- only needed for digital signatures -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.itextpdf</groupId>
        <artifactId>sign</artifactId>
        <version>${itext.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- only needed for barcodes -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.itextpdf</groupId>
        <artifactId>barcodes</artifactId>
        <version>${itext.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- only needed for Asian fonts -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.itextpdf</groupId>
        <artifactId>font-asian</artifactId>
        <version>${itext.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- only needed for hyphenation -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.itextpdf</groupId>
        <artifactId>hyph</artifactId>
        <version>${itext.version}</version>
    </dependency>




    <!-- pdfHTML -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.itextpdf</groupId>
        <artifactId>html2pdf</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.2</version><!-- para itext 7.1.5 -->
        <!--version>1.0.1</version--><!-- para itext 7.0.4 -->
        <!--version>1.0.0</version--><!-- para itext 7.0.3 -->
    </dependency>

    <!-- Styled XML parser is used by iText7 modules to parse HTML and XML -->
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.itextpdf/styled-xml-parser -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.itextpdf</groupId>
        <artifactId>styled-xml-parser</artifactId>
        <version>${itext.version}</version>
    </dependency>


    <!-- only needed for Asian fonts -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.itextpdf</groupId>
        <artifactId>font-asian</artifactId>
        <version>${itext.version}</version>
    </dependency>


    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.18</version>
    </dependency>
```

Update 2 for 2019-02-19

Opening html file with:

1)Chrome, looks ok!! All images ok.
2)Internet Explorer 8, same JPG image, and another one(PNG), do not appear on the page.
3)Internet Explorer 11, All images ok.

That confuse more to me.

Comment: Please upgrade to latest version of iText (7.1.5) and try again

Comment: Yes, i tried first iText 7.0.4 and then 7.1.5, same problem:

Comment: 7.1.5 say: Bad Base64 input character at 76: 37(decimal)
09:57:37.423 [main] ERROR c.i.s.r.resource.ResourceResolver - Unable to retrieve image with given base URI (file:/D:/PDFCONVERTER/ITEXPDF7/html/) and image source path (data:image/jpg;base64,/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQEBLAEsAAD/4Q4kRXhpZgAATU0AKgAAAAgA.........)
09:57:37.431 [main] ERROR c.i.h.a.impl.DefaultHtmlProcessor - Worker of type com.itextpdf.html2pdf.attach.impl.tags.DivTagWorker unable to process com.itextpdf.html2pdf.attach.impl.tags.ImgTagWorker

Comment: Can you please attach the full code with image for analysis?

Comment: I uploaded here:  [link](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1Aq18WMzLch5zuv1XNn8EAxXcn51rC37X) This is the HTML full code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem. The JPG base64 was corrupt. 
Their were lots of "%" characters in the HTML base64 JPG image only. When transforming XML+XSLT to HTML, the JPG base 64 turned corrupt. "%" characters werent in the original XML JPG base 64....
Now i have to look at my trasnform operation.
Thanks.